# phpmyadmin- mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch Handler

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Im trying to load my SmartFoxServer Page and a white screen with this comes up:

```html
mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch Handler 
Location: C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\class.content.php (112)
```

And I dont know how to fix it, Here is what the (112) was referring too:

```js
public function DBase($type, $params = array()) {
        if (!$this->MySQL->Connection)
        $this->SystemExit('No available MySQLi connection', __LINE__, __FILE__);
        
        switch (strtoupper($type)) {
        case 'QUERY':
            if ($Query = parent::query($params[0])) {
                $this->MySQL->TotalQuery++;
                return $Query;
            } else
```

Please help any suggestions will help. And Please dont contradict me too much. Im a beginner on this site and with the Website Hosting  server code.

Comment: That's error message from whatever smartfoxserver, not mysqli